# How to get iframe scroll position in IE using Java Script?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, scroll

```
scrollPosition = window.frames[id].document.body.scrollTop;
```

The above code doesn't work correctly. Please tell me how to correct it.

Comment: Maybe if you add some more explanations... In what way it does not work correctly, do you get some permission/access denied error from browser, or it does return a wrong value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get scrollTop in a crossbrowser way jQuery does this:

```
function GetScrollTop()
{
   var doc = document.documentElement
   var body = document.body;
   return ((doc && doc.scrollTop) || (body && body.scrollTop || 0)) - (doc.clientTop || 0);
}
```

I personally use simply this:

```
return document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop
```

Answer (score 1):

If the frame's document is located on a different domain, you will not be able to access most properties and objects on it due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that what you're looking for is easy obtainable if you're using jQuery. So that might be worth looking into?

http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/ there is also scrollTop (api.jquery.com)

Comment: Do you have an idea of what it takes to look into jQuery source code? It's simplier to look in YUI/prototype code then.