# Add X axis to No Scroll Refresh

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone help me add the X axis on my no scroll refresh. I don't want it scrolling to the top or to the left on each refresh which is very often.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function refreshPage () {
     var page_y = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop; 
     window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + '?page_y=' + page_y;

}
     window.onload = function () {
         setTimeout(refreshPage, 1700);
            if (window.location.href.indexOf('page_y') != -1 ) {
                var match = window.location.href.split('?')[1].split("&")[0].split("=");
                document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop = match[1];

                                                                }
                                  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
function refreshPage() {
    var page_y = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop;
    var page_x = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollLeft;
    window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + '?page_y=' + page_y + "&page_x=" + page_x;
}
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(refreshPage, 10000); // you can change the timer again but I don't recommend making it too fast
    var match = window.location.href.split('?')[1].split("&");    
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('page_y') != -1) { 
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop = match[0].split("=")[1]; // page_y
    }
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('page_x') != -1) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollLeft = match[1].split("=")[1]; // page_x
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's is already the behavior of the browsers (atleast, I tested in Firefox and Chrome).

Although, it is not doing it because of the way you do the reload. With the method reload it works fine.

```
//location.reload(forceGet): forceGet is false by default
//false will make it load from the cache
window.location.reload()
```

But if you really want to do it manually

```
var page_y = window.scrollY;

window.scrollTo(0, match[1])
```

In your current code, it will look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshPage () {
    var doc = document.documentElement
    var body = document.body;
    var page_y = window.scrollY || ((doc && doc.scrollTop) || (body && body.scrollTop || 0)) - (doc.clientTop || 0);
    window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + '?page_y=' + page_y;
}
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(refreshPage, 1700);
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('page_y') != -1 ) {
        var match = window.location.href.split('?')[1].split("&")[0].split("=");
        window.scrollTo(0, match[1]);
    }
}
</script>
```

I dont know what you want to do, But I would suggest to change something locally if you need and not reloading the whole page.

**Edit**

To work on multiple platforms, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347491/how-to-get-iframe-scroll-position-in-ie-using-java-script) solution.

```
var doc = document.documentElement
var body = document.body;
var page_y = window.scrollY || ((doc && doc.scrollTop) || (body && body.scrollTop || 0)) - (doc.clientTop || 0);
```

Comment: wait I use IE10 and this browser is for IE10 only and on refresh it scrolls up and to the left unless I set it otherwise. and I need to refresh my page  every 1.7 seconfds

Comment: I just tested with IE9 and the `scrollTo` seems to work. Did it worked for you?

Comment: well no i'm confused as to where to add the code I don't see how it would refresh every 1.7 seconds with what you have am I missing something? It can't scroll up or to the left.

Comment: Really? Ok. Keep the code you have right now and change 2 lines. In the method refreshPage, get the `page_y` value using `page_y = window.scrollY`. In the `onload` method, scroll the page using `window.scrollTo(0, match[1])`.

Comment: well copying and pasting what you posted in IE10 it scrolls back to the top and to the left....

Comment: You are correct. `scrollY` does not support in IE. Try the above. I just tested on IE9 and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for your help. but it still scrolls to the left on refresh

Comment: still scroll left? so why dont you do the same thing you are doing for Y to work with X? Its mostly a careful copy and paste.